# Cannot find symbol Java Initilisation RSA

Tags: java, exception, cryptography, rsa

Hi I would like to run the following command

```
// Initialise the RSA cipher with PUBLIC key
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
```

But I have the following error that I cant find any symbol in  Cipher cipher = cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

Here are the following packages I imported:

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import sun.misc.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.lang.Exception;
```

Here is the full code that acts as a server which receives incoming connection. Upon accepting connections, it will generate an AES key and a RSA Cipher, which will be used to encrypt the key

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;
import sun.misc.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Server { 
  public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException { 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15123); 
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket); 

    System.out.println("A Simple Program using RSA to encrypt a single symmetric key using");
    System.out.println("Advanced Encryption Standard (AES).\n");
    System.out.println("Generating a symmetric (AES) key...");
    try{
      KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      keyGenerator.init(128);
      Key AESKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
      System.out.println("Format: "+AESKey.getFormat());
    } catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("WRONG!");
    }

    // Create an RSA key pair
    System.out.println("Generating an RSA key...");
    try{
      KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
      // Insert your statement here
      KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
      System.out.println(keyPair.getPublic().getFormat());
      System.out.println(keyPair.getPrivate().getFormat());
      String publicKeyFilename = "public";

      byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

      X509EncodedKeySpec x509Encoded = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilename);
      fos.write(x509Encoded.getEncoded());
      fos.close();

      String privateKeyFilename = "privateKeyFilename";

      byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

      //byte[] encryptedPrivateKeyBytes = passwordEncrypt(password.toCharArray(), privateKeyBytes);
      PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8Encoded = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
      fos = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFilename);
      fos.write(pkcs8Encoded.getEncoded());
      fos.close();

      System.out.println("Done generating the key.\n");
    } catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("WRONG!");
    }

    // Initialise the RSA cipher with PUBLIC key
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    // Insert your statement here
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

    // Get the bytes of the AES key
    byte[] encryptedKey = AESKey.getEncoded();
    System.out.println("AES key:\n" + asHex(encryptedKey) + "\n");

    // Perform the actual encryption on those bytes
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
    System.out.println("Encrypted key:\n" + asHex(cipherText) + "\n");

    File transferFile = new File ("copy.doc"); 
    byte [] bytearray = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()]; 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
    bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); 
    System.out.println("Sending Files..."); 
    os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    os.flush(); 
    socket.close(); 
    System.out.println("File transfer complete"); 
  } 

  public static String asHex (byte buf[]) {

    //Obtain a StringBuffer object
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
      if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
        strbuf.append("0");
      strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    // Return result string in Hexadecimal format
    return strbuf.toString();
  }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide the precise error. I presume it is compile time? Did you setup your `import` statements correctly?

Comment: Maarten Bodewes I have done editing. Please help if you can :)

Comment: OK, great. I can see `javax.crypto.*` in there. Please also provide the exact error and location of the error.

Comment: http://imgur.com/q24jWoS

Comment: @user3448790 Hiding new information in comments is bad style. Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the variable keyPair is done in a try block. So the scope of the variable keyPair is this block. cipher.init is called outside the block, so the variable keypPair does not exists in this block.

Solution is before your try block, add:

```
KeyPair keypair = null;
```

and then just associate the value in your try block

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of seneque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268263/589259) is correct. The answer is indeed to declare the varialbe before the `try / catch`. There is however no need to initialize it with `null`. Instead, just make your error handling more specific:

```
final KeyPair keyPair;
try {
    ...
    keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
    ...
} catch(final Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Exception during key pair generation not handled", e);
}
...
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
...
```

Now because you are throwing a `RuntimeException` the compiler knows the `init` statement is never reached and hence the `keyPair` variable doesn't need to get assigned a value. If there is no exception then the `keyPair` is now both declared and initialized you won't get the compile time error anymore.

Of course, in your final code you want to work out the exact exceptions you want to catch and how to handle them. At that time you should handle exceptions based on program state and programming errors/runtime errors differently.

---

Anything *declared* between `{` and `}` becomes **out-of-scope** after the `}`. Not much used, but you can even just use `{` and `}` (without an `if` or `while`) to define a new scope. This is useful in `switch`/`case` constructs or during testing because you may get name clashes if you don't introduce a new scope.